# semanage command is not found in Centos 5.4

Tags: linux, unix, centos, centos5

I am using the Centos 5.4.
I want to run this command without quotes to allow selinux ports for http traffic.
 "semanage port -m -t http_port_t -p tcp 7000"
but error occur (semanage command is not found).
semanage is also available in this directory /usr/sbin/semanage in my OS.I already install and update the   policycoreutils-1.33.12-14.13.el5.x86_64.rpm package and already try the many solutions available on internet for this problem.
How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried `/usr/sbin/semanage port -m -t http_port_t -p tcp 7000` yet?

Comment: This command does not run.I only goes to /usr/sbin directory and saw the  semanage file.when I try the semanage command on terminal then error occur semanage command not found

Comment: I resolve the issue alvits when I try your command /usr/sbin/semanage port -m -t http_port_t -p tcp 7000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the issue when I try this command

```
/usr/sbin/semanage port -m -t http_port_t -p tcp 7000
```